# how do i call a component in react native from a native-android widget?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, react-native-cli

i am using react native cli (RN=0.61). I have a component which is for SOS message sending. I want to call this from an android widget developed using android studio (java).How can i do it ?

P.S. I have used android-studio to build the widget as there is no direct way of creating widgets using react native.

Comment: please shhow module that you created in java

Comment: It's just the basic widget code... as in i have not written anything else in the widget part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there are no methods to communicate from widget -> app. Communication in the opposite way is possible.